# when i create a MediaRecorder object by use MediaRecorder.AudioSource.REMOTE_SUBMIX

Tags: android, mediarecorder

> 05-26 16:05:59.668 19693-19914/net.yrom.screenrecorder V/ACodec:
>   [OMX.google.aac.encoder] calling fillBuffer 2881199752 05-26
>   16:05:59.668 19693-19693/net.yrom.screenrecorder E/AndroidRuntime:
>   FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                            Process: net.yrom.screenrecorder, PID: 19693
>                                                                            java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result
>   ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=-1, data=Intent { (has extras)
>   }} to activity
>   {net.yrom.screenrecorder/net.yrom.screenrecorder.ui.activity.ScreenRecordActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on an
>   uninitialized AudioRecord.
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3863)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3906)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440)
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5689)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960)
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)
>                                                                             Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: startRecording() called on
>   an uninitialized AudioRecord.
>                                                                                at android.media.AudioRecord.startRecording(AudioRecord.java:649)
>                                                                                at
>   net.yrom.screenrecorder.core.RESAudioClient.start(RESAudioClient.java:48)
>                                                                                at
>   net.yrom.screenrecorder.ui.activity.ScreenRecordActivity.onActivityResult(ScreenRecordActivity.java:127)
>                                                                                at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:6320)
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3859)
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3906) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1700(ActivityThread.java:165) 
>                                                                                at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1440) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
>                                                                                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
>                                                                                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5689) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
>                                                                                at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:960) 
>                                                                                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:755)  05-26
>   16:05:59.668 19693-19921/net.yrom.screenrecorder V/ACodec:
>   [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] Now Loaded 05-26 16:05:59.668
>   19693-19921/net.yrom.screenrecorder V/ACodec: onConfigureComponent
>   05-26 16:05:59.678 19693-19921/net.yrom.screenrecorder E/ACodec:
>   [OMX.qcom.video.encoder.avc] storeMetaDataInBuffers (output) failed w/
>   err -1010 05-26 16:05:59.678 19693-19921/net.yrom.screenrecorder
>   W/ACodec: do not know color format 0x7fa30c04 = 2141391876 05-26
>   16:05:59.678 19693-19921/net.yrom.screenrecorder W/ACodec: do not know
>   color format 0x7f000789 = 2130708361 05-26 16:05:59.678 19693-19693/?
>   I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 19693 SIG: 9

Comment: Please take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Provide your code please